# UPS suddenly restarting, what might be the cause?

Tags: power-supply, power, reboot, ups

#### Background

My UPS has a backup of about 10 mins, thus, it's battery life is good. No problems detectable.

My CPU, on the other hand, is also fine with no major hardware problems (as it looks so) except that I suspect that it's CMOS battery is weak. I can say so because once in every 4-5 days or so, my computer time resets.

I run windows 7 (I don't think computer specs matter as it's a hardware, more specifically, UPS problem)

---

#### Problem

Now on to the problem, from a few days I've been experiencing weird issues. Once in every few days (a week usually) *the UPS suddenly restarts* (I can confirm it restarts because it gives that long distinctive beep, which it gives when I start it), thus, computer experiences an unexpected shutdown. The issue looks very new to me, Googling hasn't helped. As far as the cause is concerned, I am completely blank. As I said, my UPS' battery life is good and as far as I can tell, there are no power fluctuations at the time this happens.

#### Secondary Problem

This is yet another problem, which I think is related. I've noticed that whenever I leave my UPS open after shutting down the computer, the next time I open computer, it doesn't. I mean CPU throws green light, fan runs, but the computer doesn't boot. To fix it, I usually reset the motherboard by long pressing the power button and the computer boots as normal.
Any ideas why it's happening?

Comment: Why do you turn your UPS off? They are intended to be left on all the time to help with power surges as well as provide clean power.

Comment: What? No, i don't switch off ups from power source, but my ups from providing power to cpu.

Comment: what make/model ups is it please?

Comment: Intex Protector 600va

Comment: You have 3 questions, you should really focus on one at a time.  One of my 3 UPSs beeps every so often and I can hear a relay or similar clicking.  But it does not interrupt its output.  So, I would start with the UPS.  Also measure its voltage.  You can buy cheap plug in loggers, something like this from [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Consumption-Electricity-Analyzer-Overload-Protection/dp/B07M9KJRKP).  Obviously I have no association, I dont own Amazon.

Answer (score 1):

Check the UPS status with usb/serial cable. Almost all ups vendors have software to monitor the ups health status.

If the battery itself is older than 2 years, you should replace it.
If the battery is not operated in vendors pre-defined temperature ranges, the battery might not even last 2 years.